# How to let agents select and remove an item from a list in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm relatively new to NetLogo so this may be more straightforward than I think, but I would appreciate any help.

Is there a way to let agents select a number from a list, and make it so that other agents cannot select the same number?
I'm giving each agent in a group a time to wait before they start walking. I've made a list of wait times:

```
set intervals-list [0 50 100 150]
```

I try to have each agent have a unique interval-time, but using "one-of" leads to repetition. Can I let each agent select a unique value?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could shuffle the list, then have each agent remove the number it uses:

```
let intervals-list shuffle [0 50 100 150]
ask turtles [  ;; assuming there are four turtles
  set interval first intervals-list
  set intervals-list butfirst intervals-list
]
```

Other solution approaches are possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For now there are 4 turtles, but if I change that I can just add intervals 200, 250 etc. Will using shuffle, shuffle these intervals for each run? So the 0, 50, 100, 150 order will differ each time? It shouldn't matter either way, as the turtles are the same anyway and I want to test the effect of their overall presence as opposed to looking at each individual... but I'm just wondering how it works. Thanks a lot again, will try to put this in.

Comment: When the shuffling happens depends on where you put `shuffle` in your code... not sure how else to answer.